# Shell Navigation in .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, shell, splash-screen, maui

I am using a `TabBar` in my AppShell and I want my first page to be a custom splash screen, which checks if there is a user object present and if yes, navigates to to a Home page else shows the login page.

This is working well. However, I am not able to set the splash screen as my startup screen in Shell. When I add it to the `TabBar` it is visible as an option in the `TabBar`, and if removed the splash screen is not initiated.

[image]

```xml
<TabBar Route="tabbar">

    <Tab>
        <ShellContent
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SplashPage}" />
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title="Home" Route="home">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialOutlined" Glyph="{x:Static md:Icons.Home}" />
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:HomePage}" />
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title="Invoices" Route="invoices">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialOutlined" Glyph="{x:Static md:Icons.ShoppingCart}" />
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:InvoicesPage}" />
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title="Customers" Route="customers">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialOutlined" Glyph="{x:Static md:Icons.Person}" />
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CustomersPage}" />
    </Tab>

</TabBar>
```

An empty section is being shown in the `TabBar`. How do I enable the splash screen as the entry point, and not have it show in the `TabBar`?

Comment: Does the <Shell> element containing this <TabBar> have a `CurrentItem` attribute set?

Comment: No. It does not

Answer (score 3):

For your scenario with the SplashPage I would not use the Shell at all.
Simply start your program like this in the App constructor:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MainPage = new LoadAppPage();
}
```

The `LoadAppPage` is just a normal `ContentPage`. There you can do all your initialization logic of your app, show some waiting UI, check the user, maybe show a login page.

And when you're done with all that logic in `LoadAppPage`, you can navigate from there to the `Shell` of your app by just replacing the `MainPage` of your app:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new ApplicationShell();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ShellItem Route="SplashPage">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SplashPage}"/>
</ShellItem>

<TabBar>
    ...
```

Form your Shell XAML like that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. By doing this, the Tab bar disappears entirely.

Comment: @Sam now switch the places of tabbar and shell item.